# Complex integral transforms

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integral-transforms

Is there an invertible (for some specified classes of functions) integral transform performed as a contour integral over $\mathbb{C}$, for example $F[f](w)=\oint_\Gamma K(w|z)f(z)\mathrm{d}z$ (let say, mapping analytic functions to meromorphic or whatever...), such that its inverse transform is also a contour integral $F^{-1}[f](z) = \oint_{\Gamma^\prime} K^\prime(z|w)f(w)\mathrm{d}w$, and superposition of $F^{-1}\circ F$ gives identity operator (``$\delta$-function'') by means of Cauchy integral: $\oint_{\Gamma^{\prime\prime}}K^\prime(z_2|w)K(w|z_1)\mathrm{d}w = \dfrac{1}{z_2 - z_1} + \text{analytic part}$?

Comment: The Cauchy integral itself obviously has this property, on holomorphic functions.

Comment: If $g(z )=  \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n,h(z )=  \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{ z^n}{b_n}$ both are analytic on $|z| \le r$ then $T f(s) = \int_{|z| = r} f(z)g(s/z)\frac{dz}{2i \pi z}$ and $  T^{-1} f(s) = \int_{|z| = r} f(z)h(s/z)\frac{dz}{2i \pi z}$. The Cauchy integral formula is obtained from $g(z)=h(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$. @ChristianRemling

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was very instructive example to analyze! It seems necessary to require $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ not analytic on $\mathbb{C}$ but rather on $|z|<R<\infty$, isnt it? Another subtlety nicely resides in a choice of integration contour: it shoud be away of singularities of $g,h$, and hence the best one is around infinity (for a fixed $z$, for $g(\frac{z'}{z})$ require $|z'/z|<R$) in order to have series representation.  Only taking this carefully into account indeed leads to Cauchy $\delta$-function for superposition of $T$ and $T^{-1}$! Thanks a lot for an instructive example!